# Request.ClientFilePath is visible in Watch window but not valid in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a legacy application that uses IIS rewrites to mask certain underlying folder structures. In the `Global.asax` file, there's URL validation to prevent unauthorised access to URLs.

The problem I have is that I need to access the rewritten URL as this is more consistent than the actual file path e.g. `app/example.aspx` is entered in the browser but `app/virtualdirectory/folder/anotherfile.aspx` is the file being delivered.

When debugging, I can see an object in `this.Request` called `ClientFilePath` that contains the `/example.aspx` that I need however, when I stop debugging, I cannot access this property in code. This line

```
if(this.Request.ClientFilePath == "/example.aspx")
```

produces the following error:

```
'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'ClientFilePath' and no accessible extension method 'ClientFilePath' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

There is a reference to this `ClientFilePath` property [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpRequest.cs,1484) but it's inaccessible.

What other method could I use to get the relative path, according to the client, in `asp`? I don't want to try and parse the value out of the string as I need to preserve the folder structure for other purposes and the path of the file changes under certain criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed this value in an old webform project. You can use the string path = context.Request.RawUrl;

[image: Full path]